# Ajax Validation Using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I using jquery validation plugin.

In my form i need to check whether the nick name is already in use or not.

For that they are providing `remote` key to make ajax call. For me the ajax call is working
correctly and returning true or false. But its allowing even if the returned value is false,
which should not happen.

My validation code looks like,

```
$(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            fullName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            nickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                alphaNumeric: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "NickNameChecker",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        nickName: function() {
                        return $("#nickName").val();
                    }},
                    success: function(data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fullName: {
                required: "Please Enter Your Full Name.",
                minlength: "Full Name should have minimum 5 letters."
            },
            nickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: "Nick Name should contain minimum 4 letters.",
                remote: "This nickname is already in use."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative!!!

Thanks!

**Solution:**

The solution is in my code only.

**I just removed the success part and tried. Its working great!**

Comment: What is the return value from the remote page?

Comment: @Cybernate: If nick is not in use `true` otherwise `false`

Comment: @TamilVendhan: Not an expert on the `remote` option, but none of the examples I could find showed the `success` option being specified.

Comment: @ Andrew Whitaker: Give me any of those examples. I ll try to follow them.

Comment: While client side checking is good for user experience, make sure you have a database rule to enforce uniqueness of nicknames, otherwise you're just waiting for a race condition

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, have your comment in an answer for TamilVendhan to accept it! as for the [examples](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) [this](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) is the best example for your case. Try `asdf` as username

Comment: @ifaour: Its alright, just glad he figured it out.  People with enough rep should probably vote to close (not there yet).

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: I tried to vote to close this question right after updating the question. But i am not able to judge what option i should select. Nothing matching in my case and also need more hands to close. I hope you will start to close. Or post your comment as answer, i ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Expanded explanation from comment above)*:

The `success` option is not valid for jQuery validate's remote validation.  You should be able to just specify a URL to access for validation that returns true or a falsy value/error message:

> The serverside resource is called via
>   $.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a
>   key/value pair, corresponding to the
>   name of the validated element and its
>   value as a GET parameter. The response
>   is evaluated as JSON and must be true
>   for valid elements, and can be any
>   false, undefined or null for invalid
>   elements, using the default message;
>   or a string

See the [documentation for remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) for more information on how to use the option.  Your code would probably look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            fullName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            nickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                alphaNumeric: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "NickNameChecker",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        nickName: function() {
                        return $("#nickName").val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fullName: {
                required: "Please Enter Your Full Name.",
                minlength: "Full Name should have minimum 5 letters."
            },
            nickName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: "Nick Name should contain minimum 4 letters.",
                remote: "This nickname is already in use."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Validation team advised another way to handle non-boolean APIs [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/351).

The proposed method takes advantage of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s dataFilter property.

```
form.validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "users2.json.php",
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(json.status === "success") {
                        return '"true"';
                    }
                    return "\"" + json.error + "\"";
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```